# Continuity at one point $t_0$ implies continuity at a small neighborhood of $t_0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Does the continuity of a mapping $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ at $t_0\in (-1,1)$ implies the existence of $\epsilon>0$ such that $f$ is continuous over $[t_0-\epsilon,t_0+\epsilon]\subset [-1,1]$ ?